How to smoothly hide and unhide NavigationBar and TabBar in SwiftUI at the same time with an animation in iOS 17
I would like to smoothly hide and unhide the NavigationBar and the TabBar at the same time with an animation on iOS 17 using SwiftUI.
I can get either one to animate in and out nicely if done separately but I can't get them both to work at the same time.  
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var toolbarItemVisibility: Visibility = .visible

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        TabView {
          Color.gray
            .onTapGesture {
              withAnimation {
                if toolbarItemVisibility == .visible {
                  toolbarItemVisibility = .hidden
                } else {
                  toolbarItemVisibility = .visible
                }
              }
            }
            .tabItem {
              VStack {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Text("Tab 1")
              }
            }
            .toolbar(toolbarItemVisibility, for: .tabBar)
          Color.brown
            .tabItem {
              VStack {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                Text("Tab 2")
              }
            }
        }
      }
      .padding()
      .navigationTitle("Home")
      .toolbar(toolbarItemVisibility, for: .navigationBar)
    }
  }
}


Each tab needs its own NavigationStack. The TabView should always be on top
